# UPSERT a table from another database using table alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two databases with same tables, but different data. I want to take all data from the table in the second database and update existing values in the first one. 
If there is no such entry, I want to insert the new one.
Here is my code (which doesn't work):

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET tbl1.Field1 = tbl2.Field1 
FROM [test1].[dbo].[Table1] tbl1, [test2].[dbo].[Table1] tbl2
WHERE tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO tbl1 (tbl1.Id, tbl1.Field1) 
    VALUES ([test2].[dbo].[Table1].Id, [test2].[dbo].[Table1].Field1)
```

I have following error messages.

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   The multi-part identifier "`test2.dbo.Table1.Id`" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   The multi-part identifier "`test2.dbo.Table1.Field1`" could not be bound.

I think the problem is in wrong alias usage, but I can't figure out what exactly I do wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement for this:

```
Merge   [test1].[dbo].[Table1]  As Target
Using   [test2].[dbo].[Table1]  As Source   On  Target.Id = Source.Id
When Matched Then Update
    Set Field1 = Source.Field1
When Not Matched Then Insert
        (Id, Field1)
Values  (Source.Id, Source.Field1);
```

Comment: Works as a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (tbl1.Id, tbl1.Field1) 
VALUES ([test2].[dbo].[Table1].Id, [test2].[dbo].[Table1].Field1)
```

in this statement, constants or variables only can be used.

But you probably need to use sth like that

```
INSERT INTO [test2].[dbo].[Table1] (Id, Field1) 
SELECT tbl2.Id, tbl2.Field1 FROM [test1].[dbo].[Table1] tbl1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM [test2].[dbo].[Table1] tbl2 WHERE tbl2.ID=tbl1.ID
)
```